# Solution of Bessel equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, roots

Prove that for a Bessel function in its normal form  that is: $$u'' + \left(1 + \frac{1-(4*p^2)}{4x^2}\right)u=0$$ if $p > \frac12$ then every interval of length $\pi$ contains at most one zero of a non trivial solution of Bessel's equation. I was able to solve for $p < \frac12$ and p between $-\frac12$ and $\frac12$ by Sturm comparison theorem but this for $p > \frac12$ not able to solve.

Comment: It really helps readability to format using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: the equation do not seem right.

Comment: sorry i have done it right.Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Do you mean $u''+u'/x+(1-p^2/x^2)u=0$?

Comment: yes the equation you are mentioning is also bessels but not in its normal form

Comment: Should it be $$u'' + \left(1 + \frac{1-4p^2}{4x^2}\right)u=0$$ instead? @shivam

Comment: yes it is this only

Comment: Note $*$ here is multiplication, as in computer languages, and not convolution, as in mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

Anyway if it's about $$u''+\left(1+\frac{1-4p^2}{x^2}\right)u=0$$ here's my solution:

Compare it with $$u''+u=0$$.
Observe that $$u(x) = A \sin(x-a)$$ is a solution of $u''+u=0$, & has zeros at $a$ and $a+\pi$.

If $p>\frac{1}{2}$, $1-4p^2<0$, so $1+\frac{1-4p^2}{x^2}<1$ for $x\in[a,a+\pi)$.

Now, by the Sturm comparison theorem, a solution to the proposed ODE cannot have more than one zero in $[a,a+\pi)$, as
$u(x) = A \sin(x-a)$ does not have a zero in $(a,a+\pi)$.

Comment: can you give a little more explanation of the last 2 lines of your reasoning

Comment: you do know what is the Sturm comparison theorem right? @shivam